# Variable set inside for loop not available outside

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I'm basically trying to get just a drive's freespace (I don't have powershell). 
For example, if my D: drive freespace is above 15 GB, I'll take any action.  Interestingly, the script I wrote works perfectly when I run it manually but not when I schedule it with a scheduler.

I also have **setlocal enabledelayedexpansion** at the beginning of my script, still no luck.

This is my code:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:" %%a in ("Disk_status.txt") do ( echo %%b >TEMP_Size.txt )
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:" %%a in ("Disk_status.txt") do ( set FullFreeSpace=%%b )
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-2 delims=." %%a in ("TEMP_Size.txt") do ( set FreeSpace=%%a )

echo Free Space : %FreeSpace% 

IF %FreeSpace% GTR 15 (
    echo "Space is greater than 15 GB" 
    echo FREE    : %FreeSpace% 
    GOTO TheEnd
)
```

I'm running this on 2003 server.  Feel free to suggest any easiest method to achieve the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```bat
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:" %%a in (`type "Disk_status.txt"`) do echo %%b >TEMP_Size.txt 
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:" %%a in (`type "Disk_status.txt"`) do set "FullFreeSpace=%%b"
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-2 delims=." %%a in (`type "TEMP_Size.txt"`) do set "FreeSpace=%%a"

echo Free Space : %FreeSpace% 

IF %FreeSpace% GTR 15 (
    echo "Space is greater than 15 GB" 
    echo FREE    : %FreeSpace% 
    GOTO TheEnd
)
```

---

Found the solution:  I had to use the absolute path for all the files that I've used.
Also, within for loop, while using `usebackq`, I should use ``` `` ```

```bat
:: `type <filename>`
```

This solved my problem.